# Python concordance command in NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have a question regarding Python concordance command in NLTK. First, I came through an easy example:

```
from nltk.book import *

text1.concordance("monstrous")
```

which worked just fine. Now, I have my own .txt file and I would like to perform the same command. I have a list called "textList" and want to find the word "CNA" so I put command

```
textList.concordance('CNA')
```

Yet, I got the error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'concordance'.
```

In the example, is the text1 NOT a list? I wonder what is going on here.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`.concordance()` is a special nltk function. So you can't just call it on any python object (like your list).

More specifically: `.concordance()` is a method in the [`Text` class of nltk](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.text.Text)

Basically, if you want to use the `.concordance()`, you have to instantiate a Text object first, and then call it on that object.

[Text](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.text.Text)

> A Text is typically initialized from a given document or corpus. E.g.:
>
> ```
> import nltk.corpus  
> from nltk.text import Text  
> moby = Text(nltk.corpus.gutenberg.words('melville-moby_dick.txt'))
> ```

[.concordance()](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/text.html#Text.concordance)

> concordance(word, width=79, lines=25)
>
> Print a concordance for word with the specified context window. Word matching is not case-sensitive.

So I imagine something like this would work (not tested)

```
import nltk.corpus  
from nltk.text import Text  
textList = Text(nltk.corpus.gutenberg.words('YOUR FILE NAME HERE.txt'))
textList.concordance('CNA')
```

Comment: thanks. I got it working now. But actually I only need 

textListNLTK = Text(textList) 
textListNLTK.concordance('CNA')

Answer (score 5):

I got it woking with this code:

```
import sys
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.text import Text

def main():
    if not sys.argv[1]:
        return
    # read text
    text = open(sys.argv[1], "r").read()
    tokens = word_tokenize(text)
    textList = Text(tokens)
    textList.concordance('is')
    print(tokens)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

based on [this site](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch03.html)

Answer (score 2):

In a Jupyter notebook (or a Google Colab notebook), the full process: 
MS Word file --> text file --> an NLTK object:

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.text import Text

import docx2txt

myTextFile = docx2txt.process("/mypath/myWordFile")
tokens = word_tokenize(myTextFile)
print(tokens)
textList = Text(tokens)
textList.concordance('contract')
```