# Creating a corpus from a txt file

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, topic-modeling, corpus

I've created topic models (gensim, LDAvis, ...) and now I want to look at the words from the topic models in context, for example, by looking at concordances. I have one txt file including all text I want to look at and that was used for the topic modeling. Is it possible to create a corpus from that txt file, so that I can look for concordances of certain words within this corpus?

I found something that looks promising, but I don't really know how to work with it.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('popular')

data_dir = "pathtomyfolder"

f = open(data_dir + 'corpus.txt','r',encoding='utf8')
raw = f.read()
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
text = nltk.Text(tokens)
```

How can I create a file from this that I can work with (to search for words and look at their contexts)?

Thanks!
(Btw: complete beginner with python, sorry!)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python concordance command in NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29110950/python-concordance-command-in-nltk)